# Como inserir Jquery usando EmberJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou construindo um web app com Ember.js (simples) e estou tentando utilizar algumas funções de animação com Jquey , ai vai o codigo:

```js
require(['../js/bootstrap'], function () {
  require([
   'jquery',
   'handlebars',
   'embertemplatecompiler',
   'ember'
  ],function($){
App = Ember.Application.create({
 rootElement: '#forum'
});

//Ember Routes
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', {path:'/'}, function() {
    this.resource(
        'post',
        { path: ':post_id'});
  });
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function(){
  return posts;
 }
});



 //Ember Model
var posts = [{
 id:'1',
 title:"O rato roeu a roupa",
 text:"Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis."
}, {
 id: '2',
 title:"O Hugo fujão",
 text: "Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis."
}, {
 id: '3',
 title:"Gabs Ligeiro",
 text: "Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis."
 }, {
  id:'4',
  title:"Leo Feliz",
  text:"VIsh Maria, funciono bixo!"
}];

  });
});
```

```css
/* Optimum Forum Css 
/* Discussões 
*/

.forum-discussions {
 background-color: #4E4E4E;
 min-height: 100vh; 
}

.option {
 padding-right: 1.2rem;
 padding-left: 1.2rem;
 background-color:#5A5858;
 margin-left: 45px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

a.option:visited{
 background-color: #5A5858;
}

a.option:active{
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.forum ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.forum li {
 margin-left: 15px;
}

.forum-photo {
 background-color: #eee;
 float: left;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-right: 18px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: -12px;
}

.forum a {
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bolder;
}

.forum a:hover {
 color:#DCDCDC;
}

.forum-divisor {
 background-color: #696969;
}

.forum-search {
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 width: 93%;
}

.forum-events {
 display: none; 
}

/* teste de cores */
.cor1 {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.cor2 {
 background-color: #eeee;
}
.cor3{
 background-color: #CA2B2B;
}
```

```html
<?php
    $this->extend('/Common/base');
?>
<?php echo $this->Html->css('Optimum./css/style.css'); ?>


<div class="row full-width" id="forum">
 <!--Forum Discussions / discussions (Ember)-->
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
 <div class="large-4 columns forum-discussions">
  <!-- Menu de funcionalidades -->
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="larger-2 columns">
    <a href="#" class="button round option" id ="category"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="button round option" id="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="button round option" id="add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
   </div>
   <!-- toggle effect begin-->
    <!-- category -->
    <div class="forum-search forum-events" id="categoria">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Insira uma categoria">
    </div>
    <!--search-->
    <div class="forum-search forum-events" id="find">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar Discussão">
       </div>
       <!--add-->
       <div class="forum-search forum-events" id="adicionar">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="large-12 columns">
           <div class="row collapse">
             <div class="small-10 columns">
               <input type="text" placeholder="Adicionar Discussão">
             </div>
             <div class="small-2 columns">
               <a href="#" class="button postfix"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       </div>
   <!-- end of toggle effect-->
   <hr class="forum-divisor">
  </div>
  <!-- Listagem de discussões -->
  <div class="row">
   <div class="large-12 forum">
    <ul>
     {{#each}}
     <a href="#">
      <li class="active">
       <div class="larger-4 forum-photo">
       <!--photo-->
       </div>
       <div>
        {{#link-to 'post' this}}
              {{title}}
           {{/link-to}}
       </div>
      </li>
     </a>
     <hr class="forum-divisor">
     {{/each}}
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 {{outlet}}
 </script>
 <!-- Forum Posts / Posts (Ember) -->
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post">
 <div class="large-8 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <p>{{text}}</p>
 </div>
 </script>

</div>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('Optimum.toggle');?>
<?php  echo $this->Html->script('Optimum./js/app.js'); ?>
```

Oq quero usar com Jquery é esse codigo:

```js
require(['../js/bootstrap'], function () {
  require([
    'jquery'
  ],function(){

 $('#search').click( function(){
  $('#find').toggle("blind");
 });

 $('#category').click(function(){
  $('#categoria').toggle("blind");
 });

 $('#add').click(function(){
  $('#adicionar').toggle("blind");
 });
});

});
```

Comment: Deverias ter o jQuery disponível via `Ember.$(...)` ao invés do habitual `$(...)`. Experimenta trocar `$('#search').click...` por `Ember.$('#search').click`.

Comment: Experimentei mas não funcionou Erlon =/ devo deixar o Jquery separado do arquivp app.js mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrigindo! Para aplicar o Jquery eu deveria aplicar o Document, segue o Arquivo corrigido:

```js
require(['../js/bootstrap'], function () {
  require([
    'jquery'
  ],function($){

 $(document).on('click', '#search', function(){
  $('#find').toggle("blind");
 });

 $(document).on('click','#category', function(){
  $('#categoria').toggle("blind");
 });

 $(document).on('click','#add', function(){
  $('#adicionar').toggle("blind");
 });
});

});
```

Comment: Hmmm... não faz muito sentido teres que anexar o evento de clique ao documento ao invés de a um elemento mais especifico. Parece-me que a tua solução foi mesmo passar o `$` como argumento em `...],function($){...`! Oportunamente irei aprofundar esta questão! Mas ainda bem que resolveste o problema! +1

Comment: Eu tambem não compreendi direito, mas funcionou ;)